# How can I delete specific parts of the console in c++ ? ( not a file )

Tags: c++

I'm already familiar with system ("cls") but it deletes all of the text above it and I just need to delete some of the text not all.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/fillconsoleoutputcharacter

Comment: ncurses is a common library for treating the console as a "2D grid of characters" instead of the simple "output stream" that the C++ language sees it as.

Comment: system("cls") is not C++ ;) It is asking the operating system to do it for you. 
Your probably need to use a library like [NCURSES](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/intro.html#WHATIS) to get more control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Based on the reference to `cls`, I'm assuming this is code running under Windows.]

It depends on whether you need portability.

If you want (reasonably) portable code, you can use `curses`, an old text-mode Windowing library, originally written for terminals under Unix, but now implemented on most other systems (Linux, Windows, MacOS, etc.)

If you don't care about portability, Windows provides [FillConsoleOutputCharacter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/fillconsoleoutputcharacter), which will let you fill parts of a console with arbitrary characters. To "delete" text, you normally fill that area with spaces.